# What I need to import to use index() in python?

Tags: python

I'm calling following funtion,

```
    import clr
    import System
    import ServiceDesk
    import BaseModel
    class Model(BaseModel.Model):
      def ExecuteCustomAction(self,args,env):
        resault = self.account.ExecuteService('service',args,env)
        res = {}
        if resault.Count>0:
            for customaction in resault.Rows:
                CustomActions = customaction['CustomActions']
                if CustomActions !="":
                    Lable = self.find_between( CustomActions, "Lable", "d" )
                    CallBack = self.find_between( CustomActions, "CallBack", ";" )
                    Action = self.find_between( CustomActions, "Action", "f" )
                    res['Lable'] = Lable
                    res['CallBack'] = CallBack
                    res['Action'] = Action
        return res

    def find_between( text, first, last ,self):
        try:
            start = text.index( first ) + len( first )
            end = text.index( last, start )
            return text[start:end]

        except ValueError:
            return ""
```

but when I execute this, It say

> object has no attribute 'index'

What do I need to import?

Comment: How are you calling the function? Please append that code too.

Comment: Nothing, but whatever 'text' is, it has no method 'index'. It's probably not what you think it is.

Comment: You don't need to `import` anything; you need to pass an object which has the method `index`.

Comment: I Insterted my full code

Comment: Well, what exactly is `CustomActions`…?

Comment: So `CustomActions` is not an object that has an `index` method. Post the *full traceback*, not just a hand-typed interpretation of the error message, so we can tell you more about what was passed in instead.

Answer (score 2):

This error will comes in when you pass an incorrect value of `text`. `text` has to be a string here for the index method to work. Example:

```
>>> def find_between( text, first, last ,self):
...     try:
...         start = text.index( first ) + len( first )
...         end = text.index( last, start )
...         return text[start:end]
...     except ValueError:
...         return ""
... 
>>> find_between("some_string", "s", "t", None)
'ome_s'

>>> find_between(123, "s", "t", None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in find_between
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'

>>> find_between(None, "s", "t", None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in find_between
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

---

In the code you are using, most probably, `CustomActions` is an object, and not a string. When you pass an object to the function, you will get the error as it is not a string. You can check its type using `type(CustomActions)` to verify its not a string.

---

Also, note that self has to be the first parameter, so your signature should have looked like:

```
def find_between(self, text, first, last):
```